# Parallel arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays, one which stores candidate names, and another which stores the number of votes for said candidate. I'm trying to print the maximum amount of votes and the name of the corresponding candidate; instead of an output such as `92, 4` (number of votes, index of candidate), output something like `92, John`.

This is as close as I've got to doing so:

```
puts "Candidates, index order: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4"
candidates.each { |x| puts x }
puts "Votes, index order: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4"
votes.each { |y| puts y }

votes.delete(nil)
puts "Maximum number of votes, followed by candidates array index."
puts votes.each_with_index.max { |x,y| x <=> y }
```

I'm successfully getting the index at which the max value is located, but how can I use that index to match the index of the candidates array in order to print a name rather than an index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
puts votes.zip(candidates).max_by(&:first)
```

Comment: FINALLY! I spent way too much time trying to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean the time was wasted. btw, whenever you can use [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) with two arrays of equal size you can alternatively use [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose): `[[10,23,6],["Bob", "Betty", "Bubba"]].transpose.max_by(&:first) #=> [23, "Betty"]`. Another, less Ruby-like, way is `mx = votes.max; [mx, candiates[votes.index(mx)]`.

Answer (score 0):

A one more way to do this is given below, this will work if you had multiple candidates with same votes.

```
indices = votes.collect.with_index {|ele, idx| idx if ele == votes.max}.compact
result = indices.map  do |m|
    [votes[m], candidates[m]]
end
```